Handling Multiple Clients in Reverse Proxies
I'm delving into how reverse proxies handle connections from multiple clients. Specifically, I'm interested in whether a reverse proxy can allow multiple clients to share the same TCP connection. Given HTTP/2's support for multiplexing, which allows for concurrent requests and responses over a single connection, I am trying to understand how this capability is utilized in reverse proxies in practical scenarios. I've read up on HTTP/2 and reverse proxies but found conflicting info. I expected that HTTP/2 would simplify handling multiple requests over one connection

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
